# Substring UTF-8 for both Latin, Chinese, Cyrillic, etc

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8

On Windows Phone, I want to substring any given string to what's equivalent of 100 ASCII characters in length.

String.Length is obviously useless, as a Chinese string uses 3 bytes per character, a Danish string uses 2 or 4 bytes per character, and a Russian string uses 4 bytes per character.

The only available encoding are UTF-8 and UTF-16. So what do I do?

The idea is this:

```
private static string UnicodeSubstring(string text, int length)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, Math.Min(bytes.Length, length));
}
```

But the length needs to be correctly dividable with the number of bytes used for each character, so the **last** character is always rendered correctly.

Comment: Do you mean “equivalent of 100 bytes” not ASCII characters, right? Speaking of a character is useless because of variable byte-counts depending on encoding.

Comment: UTF-8 is a variable length, multi-byte encoding. Each character can use between 1 and 4 bytes. Thus, it's not dividable by a fixed number of bytes.

Comment: if you consider surrogate pairs actual number of bytes per "complete character" in UTF8 would be even more then 4...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to simply go through the string, computing the number of bytes for each character.

If you know you don't need to deal with characters outside the BMP, this is reasonably simple:

```
public string SubstringWithinUtf8Limit(string text, int byteLimit)
{
    int byteCount = 0;
    char[] buffer = new char[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        buffer[0] = text[i];
        byteCount += Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(buffer);
        if (byteCount > byteLimit)
        {
            // Couldn't add this character. Return its index
            return text.Substring(0, i);
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

It becomes slightly trickier if you have to handle surrogate pairs :(

Comment: +1. I'd use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringWithCurrentCharacterOrPair) instead of ifs...

Comment: Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(..) can be called for each char as well. Intresting idea.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I was trying to avoid creating a new string for each character, but with GetByteCount we can reuse a single array... editing.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just curious, any idea why C# doesn't have a built in Substring to handle this?

Comment: @KenB: It's a pretty rare requirement, in my experience.

Comment: Just to clarify - I can't use Substring when dealing with Chinese characters?

Comment: @Toolkit: I don't think anyone said that. Note that the question is about taking a substring for a *byte* limit. You'll need to be aware of the possibility of surrogate pairs (where a single character is represented by two `char` values) but that's true for other normalization issues too.

Comment: I am just puzzled by a weird bug - trying to Substring a string like this মূল্যছাড় and seems it doesn't take effect

Comment: @Toolkit: Sounds like that's unrelated to this question. Ask a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet Would it be better to use the StringInfo class's SubstringByTextElements method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.stringinfo?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @JohnZabroski: Rather than `text[i]`? Potentially, if surrogate pairs have to be handled. If that's not what you meant, I think you should provide a complete code sample in your answer. You've stated that the method should be used, but given no indication *how* it should be used to solve the actual question.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's good feedback.  Until this week, despite doing .NET for 20 years and 12 professionally, I never even knew StringInfo existed.  I've updated the example and will write an official solution this week, as I need it for FluentMigrator to workaround a limitation in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to simply add "characters" (including surrogate pairs if you need to support them) to resulting string and see if it gets converted into correct number of whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

While this is an extremely old question, I believe the right approach is to use the [`System.Globalization.StringInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.stringinfo?view=netframework-1.1) class's [`StringInfo.SubstringByTextElements` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.stringinfo.substringbytextelements?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-1.1).  The major advantage of this is .NET documentation guarantees for `net461` and up, `StringInfo`'s [Notes To Callers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.stringinfo?view=netframework-1.1#notes-to-callers) guarantees conformance to the Unicode Standard Version 8.0.0:

> ## Notes to Callers
>
> Internally, the methods of the StringInfo class call
>   the methods of the CharUnicodeInfo class to determine character
>   categories. Starting with the .NET Framework 4.6.2, character
>   classification is based on The Unicode Standard, Version 8.0.0. For
>   the .NET Framework 4 through the .NET Framework 4.6.1, it is based on
>   The Unicode Standard, Version 6.3.0. In .NET Core, it is based on The
>   Unicode Standard, Version 8.0.0.

Now, how do you actually call SubstringByTextElements, given there are no examples on Microsoft Docs on how to call it?

In the `StringInfo` class, there is a note that says:

> - By calling the `ParseCombiningCharacters` method to retrieve an array that contains the starting index of each text element. You can then retrieve individual text elements by passing these indexes to the `SubstringByTextElements` method.

So:

1. Call ParseCombinigCharacters to get starting index of each text element
2. Call SubstringByTextElements using the indexes provided by step one.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is also to check if the last character is the [Unicode Replace Character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) , and remove one character until it's rendered correctly.

```
private static string UnicodeSubstring(string text, int length)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, Math.Min(bytes.Length, length));

    while ('\uFFFD' == result[result.Length - 1])
    {
        result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```